# Error "rawError ... Invalid Form Body" and Discord bot doesn't run

Tags: discord.js

I made this code for my Discord music bot and when I put my guild id in the handlers *index.js* file,

```javascript
.get("1038150024145674320")
            .commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);
```

and when I run it after that, I get this error:

```javascript
min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined,
            min_length: undefined,
            max_length: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_member_permissions: undefined,
        dm_permission: undefined
      }
    ]
  },
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: {
      '0': { type: { _errors: [ [Object] ] } },
      '1': { options: { '0': { _errors: [Array] } } },
      '4': { options: { '0': { _errors: [Array] } } },
      '8': { options: { '0': { _errors: [Array] } } }
    },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/792723109081513985/guilds/1038150024145674320/commands'
}
```

How can I fix this? What would the fixed code be?

I tried reinstalling npm packages, but they didn't work.

*Handler/index.js* code:

```javascript
const { glob } = require("glob");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const globPromise = promisify(glob);

/**
 * @param {Client} client
 */
module.exports = async (client) => {
    // Commands
    const commandFiles = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/commands/**/*.js`);
    commandFiles.map((value) => {
        const file = require(value);
        const splitted = value.split("/");
        const directory = splitted[splitted.length - 2];

        if (file.name) {
            const properties = { directory, ...file };
            client.commands.set(file.name, properties);
        }
    });

    // Events
    const eventFiles = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/events/*.js`);
    eventFiles.map((value) => require(value));

    // Slash Commands
    const slashCommands = await globPromise(
        `${process.cwd()}/SlashCommands/*/*.js`
    );

    const arrayOfSlashCommands = [];
    slashCommands.map((value) => {
        const file = require(value);
        if (!file?.name)
            return;
        client.slashCommands.set(file.name, file);

        if (["MESSAGE", "USER"].includes(file.type))
            delete file.description;
        arrayOfSlashCommands.push(file);
    });
    client.on("ready", async () => {
        await client.guilds.cache
            .get("1038150024145674320")
            .commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);

      await client.application.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);
    });

    // Mongoose
    const { mongooseConnectionString } = require("../config.json");
    if (!mongooseConnectionString)
        return;

    mongoose
        .connect(mongooseConnectionString)
        .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"));
};
```